# What does @ symbol indicates mainly in ant build xml file

Tags: ant

I have something like this below in ant build.xml

```
 <exec executable="cmd.exe" failonerror="@{failonerror}" osfamily="windows" dir=".">
        <arg line="/c npm install"/>
    </exec>
```

Can someone help me to understand what does @ denotes here?
I am not much familiar with this ant scripts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because properties can be expanded twice.

you can check it in the official doc
http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#passing-cli-args

and here for a working example
http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#propertyvalue-as-name-for-property